# How to use ScheduledExecutorService in java to call a Callable implementation at fixed interval?

Tags: java

ScheduledExecutorService has methods like scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command,long initialDelay,long period,TimeUnit unit) to invoke Runnable classes at fixed intervals. I want my Thread to return some value after execution. So I implemented Callable interface. I could not find an equivalent method for invoking my Callable class at regular interval. Is there any other way to implement this? If this is functionality is not provided by Java, what is the rational behind that decision? Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't schedule `Callable` for periodic execution since it's unclear how to return a result from such an execution.

If you have your own approach to returning the result (for example, placing a result into a queue), you can wrap `Callable` into `Runnable` and implement your approach:

```
final BlockingQueue<Result> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Result>();
final Callable<Result> action = ...;

s.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        q.put(action.call());
    }
}, ...);
```

Comment: How are you calling `q` from within `Runnable`? Isn't `q` part of an instance, while the body of `run()` is static? In other words, don't you need to pass `q` to the constructor of a custom `Runnable`?

Comment: *"How are you calling q from within Runnable?"*  The `Runnable` is an anonymous inner class.  It could be accessing `q` and `action` instance fields of the enclosing class.   Alternatively,  `q` and `action` could be local variables, since they are declared as `final`.