# Is it Possible to implement timer task with Callable Thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

unlike common thread, a callable is a thread that allow a return variable,

my question is can timertask implemented with callable thread? if yes, how does the code work?

As Timer task is using void run() for it code, how can i used timer task with callable object because callable thread used object call(), not void run()

As example, i need to implement thread which will return a boolean value (Callable thread can return a boolean value), and i need to made that thread process run periodically every 10 second (which is why i want to implement timer task)

```
public class test extends TimerTask implements Callable<Boolean>{

public void run()  //from timer task thread
{
  //timer task will only implement time task in here
  // i cant run my task here because my task have return boolean.
  // note that run() only accept void task.
}

public boolean call{  // from callable thread
  // i implement code here and end result will return true or false 
  // i have no idea how to instruct timer task
  // to keep execute my code here periodically

  //task processed . . .
  Boolean status = true;


return status;
}
```

**Answer**

I assume not possibloe or highly discourage to implement timer task on callable thread

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5102519/522444) at use of a ScheduledExectorService, but first by wrapping the Callable into a Runnable.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, this method seems unfeasible because `ScheduledExectorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()` can only take Runnable  as its parameter, thus can't return a computation result.

Comment: @roll1987: please re-read my comment. Please re-read the link. You do understand what the term **"wrapping"** means, right?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, sorry I didn't notice there's a link in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Future object to read the result with ExecutorService.

Look on the example:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class CallableTimer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyCallableThread myThread = new MyCallableThread();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    MyTask theTask = new MyTask();
    theTask.addThread(myThread);

    // Start in one second and then every 10 seconds
    timer.schedule( theTask , 1000, 10000 );
}
}

class MyTask extends TimerTask
{
MyCallableThread timerThread = null;
ExecutorService executor;

public MyTask() {
    executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
}

public void addThread ( MyCallableThread thread ) {
    this.timerThread = thread;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    System.out.println( "MyTask is doing something." );
    if ( timerThread != null ) {
        boolean result;
        Future<Boolean> resultObject = executor.submit( timerThread );

        try {
            result = resultObject.get();
            System.out.println( "MyTask got " + result + " from Thread.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println( "No Thread set." );
    }
}

}

class MyCallableThread implements Callable<Boolean> {

@Override
public Boolean call() throws Exception {
    Boolean status = true;
    System.out.println( "MyCallableThread is returning " + status + ".");
    return status;

}
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense to me.  The class that you have named `MyCallableThread` is just a `Callable`.  It has none of the behavioral characteristics of a *real* thread.